# Methods on encryption and decryption

Tags: c#, encryption

I am creating an algorithm to encrypt a string value the user inputs.
How I want to make it work is a user types in a textbox and a button will generate a random 3 digit code.

I´m having trouble coming up with the code to match the user imput with it´s correct position in the alphabet.

If the user types in "abcdt" and his random code is 324, his outcome will be "ddggv"
Here is a visual of how it works.

Alphabet-> A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z

Input->    A B C D                               T

Code:324   A move 3 spaces right= d

Code:324     B move 2 spaces right = d

Code:324       C move 4 spaces right = g

Code:324         D move 3 spaces right = g

Code:324         T move 2 spaces right = V

Any help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Okay, and what is your question?  Where is your code?

Comment: Sounds like you already have the algorithm, so did you have a question?  Note that what you describe is a cipher not encryption

Comment: This isn't encryption. This is "encryption". It's called [Viginere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vigenère_cipher) and is considered impossible weak by modern standards.

Comment: @New_Contributor Note that a cipher is used to perform encryption. There is no point at comparing them.

Comment: hint: 'move to the right' by adding n to the char value.

Comment: "I'm having trouble writing code" is not a question. Can you phrase your question in the form of a *specific question that actually has an answer*?

Comment: If your question is "how do I get started?" the answer is: if you don't know how to get started its because you picked a problem that was too hard for you. **Find a simpler version that you do know how to start, and write that**.  For example, can you implement the ROT13 substitution cipher?  That's a simpler version of your problem. If you can't implement ROT13, you can't implement your harder version. If you can implement ROT13, you can adapt your solution to your harder version. Either way, start by implementing ROT13.

Answer (score 0):

Make an array for about everything (input, alphabet, key).

Considering input[3], the D from your example input.

Get your input index in the input array. D index = 3

Apply modulo on this index and get the int from the key array. 3%3 = 0 --> key[0] = 3

Search for your char index in the alphabet array. D index = 3

Add the int you got previously to this index. 3+3 = 6

Check the index 6 for the alphabet array. alphabet[6] = G

Comment: Thank you for this! I can see the logic in this.. let me try to apply it!

Answer (score 0):

> I am creating an algorithm to encrypt a string value the user inputs.

Unless you're doing this purely for research purposes, I'd highly recommend you don't do this. Your method is not likely to be secure. Also, it's not clear why you want or need a 3-digit code based off the encrypted value. Maybe you could explain why you want that?

I'd recommend you use any of the battle-tested methods and algorithms out there already. If you want to encrypt some user input, there are many ways to do this. One way would be to encrypt the value with AES-256 with randomly generated key and initialization vector.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but since this is just "for learning purposes" it won´t be used in nothing serious.

Comment: @JuanRios ah, got it.